# Cannot run a batch file from a Windows service in Windows server 2003 OS

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am using the following code to run a batch file from C#. The following code is part of my windows service. This code works perfectly fine in Windows XP but when I deploy my windows service to Windows server 2003 OS it returns exit code 1 (failure). Does someone know what I am missing? Do I need to give some special permission to the windows service? The service is installed as a Local System service.

```
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();

        //specify the name and arguments to pass to the command prompt
        psi.FileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BatchFilePath"];
        psi.Arguments = fileName;


        //Create new process and set the starting information
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = psi;

        //Set this so that you can tell when the process has completed
        p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        p.Start();

        //wait until the process has completed
        while (!p.HasExited)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        //check to see what the exit code was
        if (p.ExitCode != 0)
        {
            logger.Write("Exit Code" + p.ExitCode);
        }
```

Comment: What is the batch file returning on success?

Comment: On windows server 2003, I can run the batch file directly from the command prompt and it works fine. but it doesnt work from the windows service.

Answer (score 1):

My next set would be to try setting the service to run as the user you're logged in as when it works. That way you'll know whether it is something specific to the Network Service account that's stopping it working

Comment: I changed the service to run as the user I am logged in as in Windows Server 2003 and it works fine. What I am wondering now is that, if I am not logged in, will it work or not? I am going to test this now. Do you think the service should be running with an account that has admin privileges? My user name with which I am logged in has admin privileges. 

Anyway, thank you for your valuable comment.

Comment: Ideally you don't want to give it admin privileges if you don't have to so give it the minimum privileges it needs to run. Probably User privileges may suffice.

Comment: You can run the service under a specific account. So even if the user is not logged in, I think it should be able to run if a specific user credentials are provided while starting the service. Once the service is installed, open the service control manager (servies.msc from command prompt) and try to change the account under which service is run. ope tis helps.